# Why are activity labels showing / not showing in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, label, visible

For some reason, my TaskForm.java activity is showing the value of @strings/app_name as it's label. I can't get it to stop showing the label, nor can I get any of my other activities to show the label so I would like to fix this inconsistency. I have looked through my androidManifest.xml, and compared my task_form.xml with other .xmls, and I have no idea what could be causing this. Apologies if this is a simple mistake, I am a beginner in android studio and I have tried to find a solution, any help would be greatly appreciated.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.C20487654_Assignment"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".NewActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".TaskForm">
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".NotificationService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="your.app.domain.NotificationService" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

task_form.xml (shows label)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/idEdtTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:hint="Enter Title" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/idEdtTask"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:hint="Enter Task" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addTaskBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Add Task"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelTaskBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

new_screen.xml (doesn't show label)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Name: "
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:id="@+id/name"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="Status: "
            android:textSize="20sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Description: "
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:id="@+id/description"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/completeBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Complete"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/green"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/removeBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Remove"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/red"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: All the activity will inherit the label from the application, if you don't set its label in the manifest file. If you want to set each activity title in code, you can use `setTitle` method. To make it disappear set an empty string. I recommend you use the support action bar with toolbar, you will have more control over the app bar this way. To hide the title with the support action bar `supportActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually realized that one of the classes was extending Activity and all of the others were extending AppCompatActivity which was causing the difference in style.